# Magento 2 product collection getSelect Order by Case unException Unknown column 'name' in 'order clause'

Tags: database, collection, product-collection, magento2.2.2

I need to use ORDER BY CASE `name` which is product name

Query:

```
SELECT `e`.*, `cat_index`.`position` AS `cat_index_position`, 
`stock_status_index`.`stock_status` AS `is_salable` 
FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `e`
INNER JOIN `catalog_category_product_index` AS `cat_index` 
ON cat_index.product_id=e.entity_id AND cat_index.store_id=1 
AND cat_index.category_id='3'
LEFT JOIN `cataloginventory_stock_status` AS `stock_status_index` 
ON e.entity_id = stock_status_index.product_id AND
stock_status_index.website_id = 0 AND stock_status_index.stock_id = 1 
ORDER BY CASE WHEN `name` LIKE '%banana%' THEN 1 
WHEN `name` LIKE '%apple%' THEN 2 
ELSE 3 END
```

`...
  $collection->addCategoryFilter($category)
  $collection->getSelect()->order(new \Zend_Db_Expr("CASE WHEN`name`LIKE '%banana%' THEN 1 WHEN`name`LIKE '%apple%' THEN 2 ELSE 3 END"));
 ...`

`Exception #1 (PDOException): SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'name' in 'order clause'`

If do `setOrder` instead of `order` then it Works but it just order alphabetically like so:

`$collection->addCategoryFilter($category)->setOrder('name', 'ASC');`

I need Expression what is going wrong?

Comment: because of name has not alias of table name so you need to specify `[alias].name` in `setOrder()`.

Comment: @HardikVisa `SELECT `e`.*, `cat_index`.`position` AS `cat_index_position`, `stock_status_index`.`stock_status` AS `is_salable` FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `e`
 INNER JOIN `catalog_category_product_index` AS `cat_index` ON cat_index.product_id=e.entity_id AND cat_index.store_id=1 AND cat_index.category_id='3'
 LEFT JOIN `cataloginventory_stock_status` AS `stock_status_index` ON e.entity_id = stock_status_index.product_id AND stock_status_index.website_id = 0 AND stock_status_index.stock_id = 1 ORDER BY CASE WHEN e.name LIKE '%banana%' THEN 1 WHEN e.name LIKE '%apple%' THEN 2 ELSE 3 END`

Comment: @HardikVisa Doesn't work `Exception #1 (PDOException): SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'e.name' in 'order clause'`